# What is the format for object names in Blender and are there any limitations?

Tags: objects, outliner

I've been using Blender on and off for a little while and have recently started trying to use it more for exporting FBX models for use in games. One of the problems I've hit is that I'm not quite sure what the object naming format is and if there are limitations.

1. Are there any characters I can't use in an object name?
2. What is the maximum name length (if any)?
3. Is it possible to have multiple objects with the same name?

Comment: I don't think there is any "standard naming format", just whatever suits your fancy. I don't know of any restricted characters, but I've never tested anything besides the usual numbers and letters (and spaces), so idk about unicode stuff. That said, it's better to have separate posts for separate questions. Imo maybe 1&2 and 5&6 can go in two posts, but the rest of the questions seem better fit to their own individual posts. Though I'm not sure if 8 is on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any ID name (objects, but also materials, textures, etc.) are limited to 63 **bytes** - since they are encoded with utf-8, it means 63 chars for basic latin alphabet, but any special character (fancy diacritics, non-latin alphabets) will use two bytes or more.

So to answer your specific points:

1. No, you can use any char you want.
2. At best, your name can be 63 char length, less if you use fancy chars.
3. No, each name **must** be unique in a given ID type (i.e. if you have a `Cube` object and try to name another one the same, it will be automatically changed to `Cube.001`). However, you may have e.g. a material, object and texture with the same names.